# Running javascript function on background while receiving push notification?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, cordova, push-notification

I know this one has probably been asked before, but not with the context of **push notifications**.

I'm developing an app using Ionic/Cordova that sends push notifications to clients, usually about new video messages for them to watch. The videos are not going to be streamed but transferred to the client-side (not my call), so I thought of implementing some background javascript function to store the video on the client-side when and while the push has been received.

I have looked on web-workers and multithreading but it needs the client-side running. The javascript code has an event listener for when pushes are being received, but of course it does not get executed until the app is being opened.

So my question is, is it even possible? I'll appreciate any words of advice on this matter, thanks!

Comment: "of course it does not get executed until the app is being opened." - maybe I'm reading this wrong: are you trying to push a video to the client who doesn't have the app open?

Comment: You got it right sir, that's one of the client's demands and he refuses to consider streaming ^_^

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm not sure you can achieve this with cordova without writing some native code...

Answer (score 0):

I already did this in my app using signalr together with push notification.  My app. is a chat app. that client X can send a rich text message with pictures or video to client Y.

when client X send message, it calls the signalr Server and the Server save the message in Server sql and save the picture or video in Web server.

if client Y is offline, it will get the message during next online.  If client Y is already on-line:

case 1: online but in foreground: signalr Server call client Y JavaScript function to update the screen and local storage, client Y see the message and picture immediately.  (and I also play a sound)

case 2: online but in background or the mobile phone in screen safe mode: signalr Server call client Y JavaScript function to update the screen and local storage, play another sound.  then send a push notification to client Y too!  So that when client Y see this notification, it open the app. and see the message in local storage.  (just like Whatsapp)

Comment: well, a little bit different, in my case the video is stored locally before the notification received!

Comment: Yes it's different but thanks for the ideas, the things is the app i'm developing would be most likely closed (probably until a notification will be pushed), so I need to come up with a way to send a file to the client before pushing a notification I guess... But that's really clever what you did there. :)

Comment: see my answer above.  'if client Y is offline' Actually means the app is closed!   so everytime the app reopen, I read the latest 10 messages from the Server first Before I display the screen.  of course, I have a button for the user to read earlier history messages.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misread it. :) So do you stream the data from the web server then? That's out of the question for my client, cause there's a lot of traffic to be involved at once here...

Comment: oh! ic! I usually have pictures instead of video!  that can't solve your problem if your client is always offline!

Comment: it depends on the size of the video, if it's too large that's difficult!

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. :) I'm playing with a 20mb video file, it took me 30 seconds to download it from the server with a 100mb connection, so I thought if I could download it "offline" somehow directly to the client, and then push the notification then it should be alright. :) It just doesn't seem possible as of yet!

Comment: can you disable the back button in your app so that your client can only go background but cannot close your app?

Comment: Quite possibly, but i'm not sure if it's a good solution since a client can always close the app in other ways. I'm looking into ArrayBuffering now, but I doubt that's gonna save the day hehe. :)